# a question about HDR image

Tags: hdr

What is the effect produced called when objects move from shot to shot while shooting an HDR ?
A) None of the other answers is correct
B) Shadowing
C) Noise
D) Ghosting
E) Moving

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not a homework service.

Comment: not off-topic merely because it's a homework question.  such questions should show some effort in researching or trying to solve yourself.  In this case a quick search would uncover the answer surely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we just give you the answer, you might learn nothing. So here goes the explanation.

A HDR image is not a single image, and it's *technically* not called a HDR image, rather a **tone-mapped** HDR image. True HDR image will show very very poorly on screens, because they are incapable of reproducing the gamut of the colours available in the photos themselves.

HDR or High Dynamic Range image is actually as combination of multiple images with different amount of exposure (though one can create HDR from a single RAW shot it produces a dull result).

Due to the inherent time it takes to process the image before you can take another one, objects in a series of photo intended to produce HDR image might have moved and shifted, creating an effect called **ghosting**.

Another thing with HDR is the amount of 'artifact' that might present in a photo due to differing lighting conditions, depth of field and object in focus.

By the way, if you can tell if a photo is a tone-mapped HDR image at first sight, it's normally overdone. Good tone-mapped HDR are generally unnoticeable by the untrained eyesight.

In fact, HDR will seem more 'natural'. Our eyes are capable of amazing dynamic ranges that a sensor/camera might never compete. In an ordinary scene, it have perfectly normal lighting condition but for you camera it might detect strong highlights and unwanted shadows.

HDR overcomes this, again, via series of images with different exposure, which after tone-mapping, can create a 'fake' (since the info isn't actually there) high dynamic range comparable to that of your eyes.

[image: St Paul Cathedral Tone Mapped Image]

What you are seeing is a tone-mapped HDR image made out of 7 different photos with varying exposures. Yet you can't really tell because it's how our eyes perceive the world.

Addition: There are HDR sensor but are very rare and hard to come by. These sensor can capture very high dynamic range comparable to that of your eyes.

---

Reference 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_imaging

Reference 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping

Comment: Limiting the definition of *High Dynamic Range Imaging* to a 32-bit floating point image file tone mapped into an 8-bit per channel raster image is very narrow. Even the references you cite above make clear that method is just *one way of many* **to reproduce a scene with higher dynamic range than the maximum dynamic range of the display medium**. What Gustave Le Gray did in the 1850s was *HDRI*. The zone system and darkroom techniques developed by Ansel Adams and others in the mid-20th century are *High Dynamic Range Imaging*. So  are many other techniques, both analog and digital.

Comment: How should I add it? Can you suggest an edit?